# RedirectToCheckout() not working when processing Stripe payments with Netlify functions (ReactJs)

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, netlify-cli

I have a function called stripe.js as follows

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_TEST);

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: "gbp",
          product_data: {
            name: "Prunus serrulata",
          },
          unit_amount: 6000,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: "/success",
    cancel_url: "/cancel",
  });
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      id: session.id,
    }),
  };
};
```

that is called from the checkout component

```
import React from "react";
import Stripe from "stripe";

const stripe = Stripe(
  "pk_test_51HqgwdGKpDMhyEuL11A63hDc42CNdjZbMH93xDPIumVyYlgGe5byVF9rXhgW0rs64r0uaDjQUqlwOUDXrbTZy9nx00cyCIwiBm"
);

const callApi = () => {
  fetch("/api/stripe", {
    method: "POST",
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => console.log(response))

    .then((session) => {
      return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
    })
    .then((result) => {
      if (result.err) {
        alert(result.err.message);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("Error:", err);
    });
};

const Checkout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={callApi}
      >
        <ChkButton>Checkout</ChkButton>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I get this in Stripe:
[Stripe session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZTJu.png)

The data is going to stripe successfully but the payment page does not load because I think I have the redirect wrong?
Can anyone point me out in the right direction please?

Any help would be much appreciated

I have been following this tutorial https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/serverless-online-payments/
trying to modify it to work in my app but I have only got this far.
I have googled it and I have not found a solution and neither in Netlify forums.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Any errors at all?

Comment: No, no errors in the console neither in the netlify server terminal. i get ◈ Rewrote URL to /.netlify/functions/stripe
Request from ::1: POST /.netlify/functions/stripe
Response with status 200 in 1013 ms.

Comment: Actually, once I added   e.preventDefault(); I saw there is an error: Error: TypeError: stripe.redirectToCheckout is not a function

Comment: What stripe client version you using?

Comment: Stripe {VERSION: '10.17.0'

Comment: There is no such version of react-stripe. Are you using this one? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/react-stripe-js 
Latest?

Answer (score 0):

`session` is currently undefined because you aren't returning the `response.json()`.

Overall, that second .then chain is not necessary as well though I assume you just have it for logging purposes. Try:

```
   .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
   })
   .then((session) => {
      return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
    })
```

Comment: Tanks for the anwsers but it did not change anything. I still get the session sent to Stripe but nothing else